Pauta de moderación - no poder hacer preguntas que den pie a debate
Esto va de una pauta de moderacion que rije aquí unicamente desde hace unos años atrás. No tiene nada que ver con ideas sueltas, ni personales, sino con el funcionamiento y las limitaciones del foro Stackoverflow en Español.
Hace unos años se estableció una norma, que no permite formular ninguna pregunta, que pueda tener varias respuestas.
Hasta ese entonces, podías preguntar sobre programación y personas entusiastas de la programación te respondían en base a su experiencia.
Sin embargo, como digo, hace unos años, se implementó una norma por la que no puedes preguntar algo que tenga mas de una respuesta, con la unica inquietud de que abra un debate.
Esto limitó las preguntas en esta comunidad a "ayudame a ver donde esta mi fallo en este codigo, que yo no lo veo.".
¿Cual es el miedo, que los miembros de la comunidad discutan al debatir? ¿A caso no puede haber otras normas de moderacion que no impidan preguntar y responder .. ofrecer respuestas concretas y practicas?
¿A caso no se pueden tener unas pautas de moderacio que impudan discutir, pero habiliten responder?
¿Pautas que no silencien las regumtas, que se basen en cambio en el respeto a las respuestas ajenas de otros en un mismo hilo, y/o en no comentar ni calificar respuestas de otros en el caso de que uno este aportando respuestas?
¿O sencillamente no hacer comentarios personales fuera de las pautas de moderacion ennun hilo que tiene varias pos8bles respuestas correctas?
Que una pregunta tenga varias respuestas, no te empuja a no querer saber nada al respecto.
Evitando habilitar un espacio ordenado  para esta comunicacion no resolvemos los problemas, dudas ni las incognitas de las preguntas.
Que una pregunta pueda tener varias posibles respuestas, tampoco te impide en absoluto responder con criterio y respeto, o compartir mas de una respuesta perfecta, diferente, con otros.
Que otra persona arroje otra respuesta, no significa que sea mejor ni peor que tu, ni que yo.
Ni tampoco que tengas que discutir con otros, porque aportéis respuestas válidas a una misma pregunta.
Más entre personas con experiencia, no les limites a depurar código, para eso hay intelisens y a mayor nivel academias.
Ofreced un espacio de preguntas y respuestas de verdad, y no una comunidad de personas depurando código.
Eso no son preguntas, es depurar código.
Hoy la sociedad desvaloriza la experiencia. La experiencia es el mayor de los valores humanos. Pronto la IA programará con solo decirle técnicamente lo que quieres. Pero ... silencia todo lo que no sea pedir depurar código, no vaya a ser que discutan (paradójico).
Estudia por ti mismo, porque cuando por no reconocer un error, decidas tirar para adelante, no estarás cambiando la realidad por ello, sino cercenando tu potencial, y extralimitando tus posibilidades. Y cuando grupalmente una comunidad decida no reconocer un error, ocurrirá exactamente igual que a nivel individual.
Una pregunta con una sola respuesta, ni siquiera puede dar pie a un debate.
Y una pregunta, que solo permite una respuesta, no equivale a "Me falla este código, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a ver porque esta fallando".
No. Por mas que pueda ser compleja la respuesta, o que no traiga código con bugs la pregunta:
Una pregunta con una sola respuesta, puede perfectamente formularse con palabras como las personas, no forzosmente por código, y resolverse igualmente, como personas (por escrito, usando lenguaje natural)
No obstante, cuando existe voluntad de alcanzar el conocimiento, y aportar información,
Cuando lo que se impone es el respeto a la experiencia y las buenas prácticas, incluso el aportar diversas formas de hacer algo, es una bendición de conocimiento y expansión.
Se puede aprender de todo, cuando existe un espacio en el que poder comunicar, y no unicamente dar cabezazos de aprendiz con el código.

"Hace unos años se estableció una norma, que no permite formular ninguna pregunta, que pueda tener varias respuestas." esto no es cierto, las preguntas pueden tener tantas respuestas como sea necesario. Lo que si, solo una se declara como respuesta correcta.  Ahora no entiendo la idea de este post. Estas queriendo abrir un debate sobre las preguntas que se cierran como discusion?

Si. En cuanto una pregunta no tiene codigo con bugs, se concluye que puede dar pie a debate, porque puede tener varias respuestas, y dar pie a discusion. Y en lugar de habilitar ese espacio de moderacion, para que puedan darse respuestas con respeto, se corta por lo sano las preguntas. Al poner la benda antes de golpe, no se permiten ni las preguntas ni las resuestas, como no sean de tipo, "por aqui tengo mi codigo con bugs, no se donde falla, busco ayuda para depurarlo". .. Eso no es Preguntas y Respuestas, es depuracion de codigo.

No es lo unico que se admite.. creo que esta confundido... que tipo de pregunta te parecio que merecia quedar abierta y no lo fue?

He tenido un monton de preguntas en los ultimos años. Si la pregunta puede tener varias respuestas, y no es un codigo con bugs, dicen que dar pie a debate, y se cierra. Por tanto, si no tiene un codigo con bugs, es imposible formular una pregunta que pueda tener varias respuestas, porwue "puede dar lugar a discusión". Me refiero a la norma que impide hacer preguntas que puedan dar lugar a varias respuestas, sin codigo, y si no se moderase de otro modo, dar lugqr a una discusion, que directamente impide pregintar y responder en esos casos.

Eso no es cierto.. hay montones de preguntas sin codigo que estan abiertas y reciben respuestas. Si queres podemos charlar en el [chat].. pero las preguntas que se cierran son las que llevan a discusiones sin sentido como por ejemplo que lenguaje de front me conviene usar...

Pues yo teng una coleccion de pregintas con sentido, y auto respondidas, y con pregintas ennStakOverflow dn Ingles respondidas, qie han sido cerradas por esto. Esa pauta se aplica asi, sistematicamente. Y si, si es cierto, tengo una coleccionnde temas cerrados, que antes de esa norma no se cerraban y si se respondian en este mismo foro, y sin discutir, de buenas formas.

Entra en mi perfil, agarra las 4 respuestas que tienen mas votos de las mias, y decime cuantas de esas son de depuracion de codigo.

Yo necesito ejemplos de lo que decis. No veo nada en tu perfil sobre lo que comentas aca. o sea, lo que pasa en SO en ingles, es cosa de alla eh... aca tenemos nuestras propias reglas...

En fin, de lo que hablo es que no entiendo, cuestiono, y no me parece adecuado, como se puede ver venir una discusion en cuanto ven la pregunta, que va de programacion, y es concreta, y cerrarla como han hecho un monton de veces. Y personalmente me argumentaron, que al poder tener varias respuestas, podia dar lugar a debate/discusion.

Ejemplos de eso... si queres plantear un error al cerrar una pregunta debes darnos ejemplos... a mi no me parece que sea como estas diciendo, asi que si tenes ejemplos los vemos puntualmente, y si se cometio un error se arreglara...

En mi perfil quiza, deben estar esos temas cerrados. Pero ¿como esta redactada esa norma? ¿Y como se aplica? No pude volver a formular mis preguntas desde entnces. Yo, ejemplos, pero si fueron cerrados todo esos temas estos años .. estan ahi, en este foro. En fin. Ahora voy por la calle. Es la pauta, y/o la falta de.claridad para saber como y cuando se debe o no aplicar la pauta, o la redaccion de esta pauta. Pero bueno, por ahora no tengo mas datos que aportar sobrw esto, porque voy caminando por la calle.

Demasiado largo, no lo lei. La brevedad es una virtud

No veo preguntas cerradas en tu perfil.. veo preguntas eliminadas por sus autores.  La pauta de cerrar una pregunta por discusion es clara, si la pregunta lleva a una discusion sin sentido (que es mejor? cual me conviene usar?) entonces se cierra...

Me parece a mi que luego de haber tenido temas cerrados los eliminé. Hablo de preguntas con sentido. Ahora, ¿Como puedes anticipar al ver una pregunta,  sobre programacion concreta .. que dsra pie a debate? Osea yo me pregunto, porqie se puede cerrsr una pregunta tecnica, con la idea de que pueda dar lugar a discusion. Lo que habra qie evitar es que se puedan dar.discusiones. Y no cerrar temas conforme ves la pregunta y se.dice ... puede dar lugar a discusion ¿Porque? A caso no puede habalr cada uno por si mismo sin meterse con el de al lado?

"¿A caso no se pueden tener unas pautas de moderacio que impudan discutir, pero habiliten responder?", las respuestas que son basadas en el documento [ask] se pueden responder y comentar, también puedes discutir en él [chat].

Yo veo las preguntas cerradas. Inclusive las eliminadas. Y no tengo pautas de lo que decis. Cuando seas mas claro, continuare la charla con vos. Por ahora, solo parece una queja sin fundamentos...

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque divaga sin proponer nada concreto

A ver Candid Moe. Por partes, luego de que la pauta previa de prevenir discusiones de debates, prejuzga preguntas, en lugar de las discusiones mismas. Tambien prejuzga las motivaciones de quien hace las preguntas ..-podria ser un estudiante perezoso xa no teclear- Hace responsable a quienes hacen las preguntas, de que qienes redopondan no vayan a dar respuestas tecnicas .. sino un una discusion de salón. Pero tambien penaliza a quienes preguntan como hacer cosas concretas que no haya en la red, por culpa de los que piden ejercicios de perezosos- Por tanto, castiga a todos sin preguntar asi.

La verdad es que si lo que se quiere es que nadie pueda hacer una pregunta legitima, que apunta a saber como hacer algo, y que nadie pueda obtener respuestas a preguntas que permitan averigusr y aprender ... para evitar discutir y que haya que pida resolver ejercicios de cero ... pues entonces se puede quedsr todo como está, pero a mi me parece matar moscas a cañonazos. Ademas es castigar justos por pecadores, y anticiparse ....

y controlar las cosas antes de qie ocurren, tsmbien es juzgar las motivaciones de todos pensando mal, asi como silenciar y censurar todonlo que parezca que pueda suscitar algo malo, por si a caso ... es un exceso de anticipacion, limitacion de los inputs, y por tantp del tipo de respuestas y aprendizjaje que ha dejado de ofrecer y permitir  este espacio. Y por todo esto, para ajusticiar a quienes tiene la motivacion de la pereza, o del discurso no-tecnico, van y le meten un hachazo a los inputs ....

/preguntas de todos los miembros, sin mramientos de cuales puedan ser sud motivaciones, o de cual puedan ser las respuestas que den otros miembros. Bueno, enhorabuena. Tambien pueden cambiar el nombre del espacio, porque no son QuestionAndAsks. Sino en coherencia, CodeFailsAndDebugging Community Entusiasts

así no funciona el sitio ...

El sitio es como una ruleta rusa ... colocas un contenido esperando no dispararte en el pie ... eso quiere decir que hay multiples factores y no necesariamente las reglas del sitio que determinan si la comunidad le agrada o no el contenido que agregaste. debido a la sinergia y el funcionamiento del sitio ... la comunidad tiene la última palabra ...

Encontraras preguntas super malas... con todos los posibles errores ... pero puede ser que la comunidad le interese y no le haga nada a la pregunta...

tambien existen respuesta super bien elavoradas, con el resultado esperado y adecuado ... y es mal recibida ...

yo te recomiendo enfocarte en ayudar y pasar de las opiniones cerradas ... y de los efectos colaterales ...

Toda tu perorata se cimienta en un malentendido:

Sin embargo, como digo, hace unos años, se implementó una norma por la que no puedes preguntar algo que tenga mas de una respuesta, con la unica inquietud de que abra un debate.

En programación no suele haber una única respuesta para un problema, así que la premisa de "prohibir preguntas que tengan más de una respuesta" es falsa.
Lo que no se quiere es preguntas mal formuladas, ya que cualquier respuesta que se de será inevitablemente mal formulada.
Por ejemplo, preguntar:

"¿Puedo compilar para la plataforma Achilipú?"

Puede tener como respuestas válidas "Si", "No", "Depende" aunque ninguna de esas respuestas sea útil. Además de que puede dar lugares a respuestas como "La plataforma Achilipú está en desuso, mejor usa Achurunflé" que aún pudiendo ser válida no aborda el tema de la pregunta.
Pero la misma pregunta formulada como:

"Tengo el compilador X versión A.B.C y me da el error E en la plataforma Achilipú ¿Cómo lo soluciono?"

Es difícil que de lugar a una familia de respuestas inútiles aunque válidas.

Espero haber aclarado tu malentendido, en resumen: No se prohíben preguntas con múltiples respuestas, las múltiples respuestas a preguntas forman parte del alma del sitio. Lo que se intenta es evitar preguntas que no fomenten respuestas útiles.

El calificativo perorata, es notoriamente despectivo, pese a todo, parece que no has profundizado en la lectura del mismo. Es incierto lo que estas sosteniendo como argumento, porque tal como ha dicho Yuseff, en muchos casos la ambiguedad de la pauta, da lugar a interpretaciones al aplicarlar que es el caso, y las consecuencias sobre preguntas cerradas, y por tanto sin respuestas. No, estoy, hablando de preguntas sin sentido. Pueden dejar de tratar de desviar la atencion, porque precisamente lo aclaro de todas las formas posibles. De modo que, nada que ver con lo que estoy exponiendo PaperBird

A parte, se trata precisamente de la ambiguedad del reglamento que ha descrito Yussef, y la subjetividad con la que se interpreta en muchos casos, de lo que hablo. No es una confusion mia. Recuerdo un saco de preguntas qie se me cerraron casi directamente, porque, "pueden dar lugar a varias respuestas, no tiene codigo, y puede dar lugar a un debate de opinion" ... y eso es.lo que me dijeron. Asi qie hablo de un problema real, no de una mal entendido de mi parte. De modo que no insistan en esto por favor, no es el caso.

La pauta no es ambigua: Se pretende desincentivar preguntas que no den lugar a respuestas útiles. Es claramente un malentendido por tu parte porque el objetivo del sitio nunca fue "no puedes preguntar algo que tenga mas de una respuesta", de ser así: cada hilo permitiría una única respuesta.

Me estoy remitiendo a las palabras que ha dicho Yuseff en este hilo. La interpretacion de esta pauta, pero no en su totalidad, ni la parte que estais repitiendo. Sino la que reseña que una pregunta de lugar a devolver opiniones. Y repito, no el proposito de la pauta, sino la interpretacion de su escueto desarrollo, y la amplica cantidad de casos en que ciertos moderadores interpretan, que al no tener codigo, puede dar lugar a un debate de opinion, e infinitas respuestas. Entonces, no son las opiniones irrelevantes ni la charla lo que se modera, sino la pregunta la que se cierra.

Que entre vosotros no haya ocurrido que os hayais cerrado de forma tan estricta temas semejantes, no significa que no haya ocurrido con otros usuarios. Ha ocurrido. Cuando un tema se cierra, el asunto queda fuera de ser reconsiderado. Esto no debiera quedar abierto asi, a la subjetividad, siendo imprevisible cuando te pueden cerrar o no una pregunta, por ser opinable. Que no se deba opinar, qie se deba responder. Pero que no se cierren preguntas en general porque pudieran dar lugar a una charla de opinion, en el caso en que se puedan responder tecnicamente.

xq, sigues malinterpretando la motivación. Vuelve a leer, pero con detenimiento: "Se pretende desincentivar preguntas que no den lugar a respuestas útiles", en tu más reciente ejemplo: una pregunta sin código no es un tipo de pregunta que en un sitio sobre programación vaya a dar lugar a respuestas útiles y por ello se desincentiva.

"una pregunta sin código no es un tipo de pregunta que en un sitio sobre programación vaya a dar lugar a respuestas útiles y por ello se desincentiva." PaperBirdMaster ... "..entra en mi perfil, coje 4 preguntas de las mis, y dime cuantas tienen codigo" gbianchi. "una pregunta no tiene pirque tener codigo" ... PaperBirdMaster aqui, comentó, que una pregunta sim codigo no, es un tipo de pregunta qie vaya a dar respuestas utiles. ...... ¿Veis? diferencia de criterios, y todo porque el reglamento no aclara, que no se trata de que no tenga codigo, sino de que pueda swr respondida tecnicamente.

@xq_t_impiden_borrar_tus_resp serías tan amable de añadir el link a esas preguntas tuyas sin código? Sería de mucha utilidad, ya que sinceramente me ahorra un par de clicks y scrolls. Gracias

Nunca dije que se prohibieran las preguntas sin código, dije que se desincentivan. Y se desincentivan por un buen motivo: son propensas a no generar respuestas de calidad, entre tus preguntas sin código que he visto hay varias de "¿cómo hago esto?" que no incluyen ni un atisbo de haber intentado hacer nada, sinceramente yo habría cerrado esas preguntas por los motivos que ya he mencionado.

El reglamento dice:

Algunas preguntas subjetivas están permitidas, pero “subjetivas” no
significa “vale todo”. Se espera que todas las preguntas subjetivas
sean constructivas ¿Qué significa eso? Las preguntas subjetivas constructivas:

inspiran respuestas que expliquen el “porqué” y “cómo”
tienden a tener respuestas largas no cortas tienen un tono constructivo, justo e imparcial
invitan compartir experiencias en lugar de opiniones
insisten que las opiniones sean respaldadas con hechos y referencias
son más que simplemente diversion social sin sentido


Esta norma tiene al menos 2 problemas:

Es ambigua y libre a interpretaciones. El típico debate de "windows vs linux" a alguien le puede parecer una pregunta constructiva y otros una discución bizantina
Se pone mucha carga en la respuesta. Si la respuesta explica el "por qué", es justa y está respaldada, entonces la pregunta es válida. Esto provoca un caso muy típico, que es cuando una respuesta salva a la pregunta. Pero esto solo pasa, cuando se responde antes que se moderé la pregunta

¿Por qué este tipo de preguntas se cierran?
En la práctica, yo veo 2 situaciones que se suman:

Existe un grupo de moderadores muy severos. Otros que, si no ven código la pregunta no es válida, y otros que "pesan" la pregunta, es decir si es muy corta no es válida.

Los que preguntan no lo hacen de la mejor forma. Por ejemplo "Cual es mejor forma de hacer A", es imposible de responder tendría que probar todas las formas posibles y determinar la mejor. Una mejor pregunta sería "Hay una mejor forma de hacer A (mostrando como lo está haciendo en el momento)", y si bien está mejor aún no es suficiente, ya que igualmente es ambigua ¿mejor en qué sentido?, entonces hay que explicar los criterios



Todo lo anterior es mi apreciación personal de como veo que funciona el sitio actualmente. Y si quieres cambiar esto, puede elevar una propuesta (aquí en meta) que exponga claramente los cambios que tu harías y las razones que la justifican, y no estaría mal agregar ejemplos reales de casos donde aplica.
Otro camino, es que ganes suficientes puntos para votar reabrir preguntas,


Invitan a compartir experiencias en lugar de opiniones.

Esta parte del reglamento, esto ..

Apunta a "que" es lo que se debe evitar, que las preguntas den lugar a opiniones (cuestion de gustos, no algo puramente tecnico y objetivo).

Pero no explica el "como" se debe identificar una pregunta que en si misma, esta enfocada en producir un debate de opinión.
Al no detallarse en el reglamento, "como" se debe evaluar si una pregunta, es unicamente de un ambito de opinion
Cada moderador, debe interpretar, que pregunta puede invitar a dar opiniones o no, segun su propio criterio subjetivo, sin ningun tipo de guia que unifique el diganostico de cada pregunta.
Esto es debido a que en este punto del reglamento, se apunta a lo que se quiere conseguir, que no se den charlas de opinion, sino respuestas tecnicas, moderando las preguntas susceptibles de generarlas.
Pero no indica ni explica el "como" se debe identificar la naturaleza de estas preguntas, y a esto a es lo que estamos refiriendo como aplicacion subjetiva, y ambiguación de la pauta.

Por otro lado. Cuando digo "puede tener muchas respuestas, dar lugar a un debate de opinion", me estoy refiriendo a lo que me dijeron literal y puntualmente para aplicar esta pauta y cerrarme temas, y no la la redacción de la pauta como tal.

Te pregunto otra vez.. quien te dijo eso? cuando te lo dijeron? contra que preguntas? Todo esto, suena a un berrinche, pero te pedi varias veces que me dieras ejemplos claros y concretos y no los tenes. Y la regla es clara, no es confusa como dice Yusef, la pregunta debe tener una respuesta que no se preste a debate. Puramente eso.

@gbianchi El texto que cité dice textual: Algunas preguntas **subjetivas** están permitidas, la RAE define subjetivo como: Perteneciente o relativo al sujeto, considerado en oposición al mundo externo por tanto 2 sujetos pueden tener 2 respuestas distintas a la misma pregunta. Además, que pones la carga en la respuesta ...debe tener una respuesta que no se preste... y como él que pregunta va a saber eso? si por algo pregunta, porque no sabe.

Coincido 100% con lo que comenta Yussef. Por otro lado, en esos casos, me anularon/cerraron las preguntas, me sentí frustrado y las eliminé, despues de todo me estaban diciendo que no eran validas. Pero esto no tiene que ver conmigo, sino con la forma que el no saber "como" y en que punto establecer el limite, de lo que es una pregunta -de opnion- y lo que arroja respuestas de valor. E incluso el hecho de que una misma pregunta podria dar lugar a ambas cosas, porque depende mas de las respuestas en ultima instancia.

Vuelvo a decir. Yo puedo ver (y yussef tambien) las preguntas supuestamente eliminadas.. entonces, otra vez.. ejemplos...

@Yussef insisten en poner la carga del lado equivocado.. si varias personas piensan que una pregunta es subjetiva, se cierra.. si no hay personas que piensen lo contrario, quedara cerrada... entonces, donde esta el problema??? si no estas de acuerdo con un cierre, se discute en la pregunta, o en meta, o donde corresponda.. ningun cierre es definitivo, ahi radica todo el problema... se cierra para evitar futuros problemas, no mas...

Si la pregunta es "cual es el mejor color para mi footer" entonces, si, la carga de la subjetividad cae sobre las respuestas, porque todas las respuestas van a llevar a una discusion...

@gbianchi Si tu dijeras "si varias personas piensan que una pregunta es subjetiva y además no es constructiva, se cierra.." Estaríamos de acuerdo, pero justamente se olvida esa última parte.  Nosotros podemos estar de acuerdo (o no) con la norma, pero de que dice que algunas preguntas subjetivas valen, lo dice y creo que no hay otra interpretación del texto (¿o sí?). Luego determinar cuando una pregunta subjetiva es válida (es constructiva) es lo que podríamos discutir, pero ni siquiera estamos de acuerdo en lo primero

Aquí un ejemplo -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/366797/301324 cuya respuesta está basada en la experiencia y a mí me parece correcta (habrá alguien que piense distinto?). Luego hay preguntas de ayuda con un modelo de datos, que pueden tener varias respuestas distintas (no veo lo malo en eso). Otros preguntan por "mejores prácticas" que pueden responderse con experiencia y además con citas bibliográficas. Es decir, cerramos preguntas, que incluso con la normativa actual podrían quedar abiertas.

Igual estos temas los hemos discutido 100 veces, y si a mí que me gusta debatir ya me tiene algo aburrido, me imagino como estarás tu y el resto.

Y digo yo  si el problema son las discusiones, ¿Porque no se moderan las respuestas que no son tecnicas en lugar de las preguntas? Hay preguntas que se pueden responder de ambas formas, y pertenecen al ambito del foro. En la medida que el reglamento tal cual.esta da lugar a tantas revisiones y cierres por error, precisamente la.subjetivodad de la pregumta, se convierte en sibjetividad de la.moderacion y el cierre .

Y asi tal cual está en ese punto, tiemes un: reglamento subjetivo. Me cuesta demasiado ver esas dos palabras juntas.

@Yussef si tiene varias respuestas y son todas correctas, no va con el formato de nuestro sitio. Si queres cambiar eso, sos bienvenido a discutirlo con la comunidad (yo solo soy uno)... No entiendo porque no entienden eso... y para ejemplos de 4 años atras, mejor no poner nada... ni siquiera la cerro un moderador (y eso que a esa altura eramos los mismos que ahora)... Entonces, hablen con la comunidad.. pero si la comunidad no les contesta, por algo sera...

Cuando digo que puede tener varias respuestas correctas, me refiero a varias respuestas que si tiemen codigo. Existen siempre distintas formas de desarrollas codigo para hacer una misma cosa.

Señores, si que hice una propuesta, os veo a muchos repitiendo que no hay ninguna propuesta de mi parte .. y eso es falso, hace ya varios dias.. La voy a poner desde el principio del texto, para que mas seguramente no vuelva a pasarse por alto. Sin más preambulos ..
Propuesta de enmienda a la pauta que evita discusiones y debates de opinión, para adjuntarlo al reglamento:
En todos los casos en que la pregunta:

Pueda ser respondida de forma técnica y comprobable;

Apuntando a averiguar como resolver algo descrito técnica y correctamente (de acuerdo al reglamento);

Corresponde al ambito de este espacio, programación;


[ NO podrá ser catalogada de ningun modo como una pregunta -de opinion-, para un -debate-, ni que pueda excusar una -discusion- ]
(incluso si no trae codigo y puede tener un número indeterminado de respuestas técnicas válidas):
En estos casos, si surje una opinón vacía de rigor tecnico y objetividad, se moderará esa respuesta.
[ Permitiendo asi que toda pregunta tecnica de naturaleza abierta, pueda obtener respuestas tecnicas ]
(Sin cancelaciones preventivas).

~ Bases y fundamentos de esta propuesta. - Que es, como funciona y porque ...  ~
Todas las preguntas que apuntan a como hacer algo programando ...
Pueden suscitar respuestas tecnicas, largas que el expliquen como se hace y porque.
Más alla de que, sí alguien quisiera responder como en una charla de opinion personal tambien pudiese hacerlo: eso, no puedes penalizarselo a quien pregunta, porque la pregunta si fue tecnica y orientada a resolver un problema. Y por tanto la pregunta es constructiva, tecnicamente perfecta, impecable.
Igual que 4 codigos diferentes pueden hacer bien un mismo desempeño/tarea ..
Desde experiencias excelsas, tambien se puede responder con codigo, y/o tecnicamente, varias respuestas correctas, que diriman formas correctas de hacer algo.
Y si solo hay una forma correcta de hacer algo, asi lo veremos en la respuesta; Pero nada de eso justifica en base a hechos, cerrar una pregunta tecnica sin codigo.
Es incierto ademas, que la pregunta sin codigo invalide posibles respuestas tecnicas con codigo, con sus indicaciones de como se hace y porque.

Respondiendo a Candid Moe
Prejuzgar que alguien quiere evitar picar codigo, para no estudiar y que otro le haga los deberes es prejuzgar su motivacion (no respondan ejercicios y ya. Pero cerrais muchos temas que no los son, asi que no se excusen en esto)
Y sin embargo cuando sirven de excusa para cerrar todos los temas que no tienen codigo, se hace responsables a todos los demas usuarios (por un prejuicio de forma), sin pararse a pensar que:
1º no puedes saber con certeza su motivacion, asi que prejuzgas a todos generalizando por unos pocos.
2º Inhabilitas preguntas que podrían arrojar nuevos conocimientos e informacion a la internet hispanohablante; Codelines buscados que atraerían las busquedas y el interés sobre estos temas, en la red;
(Al cerrar todos estos inputs, Impides dar recorrido al Know How (saber como, marco de conocimiento) fuera del ambito del sistema de estudios de titulacion y la gente que tiene acceso a modulos, carrera o ciertos recursos de estudio).
3º Cabe que aun no esten respondidas en otras partes de la red, impidiendo que Stackoverflow ES atraiga otros usuarios que busquen saber exactamente como hacer estas cosas en concreto. (.. de temas que se cierran)

Respondiendo a gbianchi sobre "¿Cual es el problema de que se cierren ciertas preguntas si a algunos moderadores les parece inadecuada por -poder suscitar debate-, si luego se puede reclamar en meta y reabrir la pregunta?"
1 Que es impredecible saber como se debe formular este tipo de preguntas.
2 Que es un modo sumamente ineficiente y tortuoso de moderar todo un amplio e indefinido conjunto de preguntas, segun el parecer de grupos variables de mods para cada pregunta. (reglamento: conjunto de reglas claras, objetivas, comprobables, igualitarias y predecibles)
3 Que la decision final de reabrir o no cada pregunta, queda en manos exclusivamente de los moderadores, al tiempo que no esta basada en criterios fijos y comprobables. Y por lo tanto son de nuevo decisiones impredecibles, no basadas en hechos, principios ni pautas reglamentarias.
4 Que no tener unas reglas claras (reglamentarias, objetivas) para este tipo de preguntas, desincentiva la participacion en el foro en la medida que ves que otras preguntas similares quedaron y fueron respondidas, miemtras la/s tuyas, en otros casos no.
Y no existe una explicacion clara, objetiva y trazable para esto, sino una decision eventual y arbitraria (no basada en reglas), tomada desde el equipo de moderadores. Con lo cual, todo queda en la subjetividad, con la pretension de combatir la subjetividad.

En el reglamento pide que se invaliden aquellas preguntas subjetivas, susceptibles de generar opiniones o debates.
¿Como es posible saber que una pregunta del tipo "¿Como se puede hacer X cosa en lenguaje Y?" va a generar un debate en lugar de respuestas tecnicas largas, explicativas y con codigo si fuese necesario?
A menos que puedas conocer el futuro no puedes saber unicamente viendo la pregunta, que esta va a generar una coversacion de salón ni un debate de pareceres. Y como no lo pueden saber, cierran preguntas tecnicas sobre programacion [sin codigo] con un abanico de excusas y prejuicios. "Esas preguntas las hacen los vagos", "esta pauta del reglamento es clara y esta todo bien asi".
Y de esta forma, juzgan la minima posibilidad de que alguien pudiera opinar de forma personal no-tecnica, una pregunta perfectamente tecnica sobre programación.
Juzgando a quien pregunta, por adelantado, para acallar lo que pudiera aportar/expresar/opinar quienes respondan, al mas puro estilo Minority Report. Es excesivo, exajerado e injustificable, de acuerdo a las motivaciones descritas en el reglamento.

Preguntas como ¿Que es mejor Windows o Linux? estan propiamente fuera del ambito de la programación. Sobre estas u otras fallas (de acuerdo al reglamento) en las preguntas, para mi no hay discusion, porque caen fuera del ámbito de enfoque de este espacio.
Asi que tampoco pueden servirme de excusa para silenciar todas las preguntas técnicas sin código, orientadas a resolver un problema programando.
Gracias, especialmente a Yussef y a Jorgesys por el apoyo a este hilo y reflexión;
Gracias también a todos en general por vuestra mente abierta para poder hablar y debatir este asunto.
Bendiciones.

Aclarar que [es.so] no es un foro. Por otro lado tu propuesta es básicamente permitir que preguntas tipo: cómo hacer X en lenguaje Y que no muestran un ejemplo mínimo verificablesean aceptadas. En lo personal discrepo y debo votar en contra a tu propuesta ya que considero que este tipo de preguntas sólo sirven para atraer a los flojos y vagos que esperan que otros hagan el trabajo por ellos. Felizmente muchos (la mayoría diría yo) han optado por GPT, lo que hace que estas preguntas sean menos frecuentes en el sitio.

Mauricio, ya hace dias que dejé de decir foro. De modo que ¿De foro me hablas? No he vulto a llamarlo foro hace dias.

Y, a ese respecto de los flojos, mi propuesta tiene una respuesta argumentada. No toda posibilidad cabe dentro de los flojos. Se está generalizand sin parar a pensar todo lo negativo que eso implica para todos los usuarios. Leelo y responde a ello por favor. Por que tu argumento de los flojos es identico al de Candid Moe, pero no responde a todo lo que estoy explicando aqui respecto de ese punto. Antes de rechazar, leed entero el aporte. Otro modo se repiten y repiten ideas sesgadas mecanicamente, de puro apego a las propias ideas. Debate, contrargumenta mis argumentos, reflexiona xa aportar.

Ademas, en ejemplo minimo verificable, lo que dice es en base a "Cuando preguntas un problema causado por tu codigo" No habla en ningun momento de cualquier otra pregunta en que no sea el caso de que tu problema resida en tu codigo. Ni dice que este sea el unico tipo de pregunta valida, condicionada por lo tanto a tener un ejemplo minimo de codigo verificable. Sino solo en el caso en que estas programando de hecho un codigo, y este tiene errores, y tu pregunta trata de ello. "Cuando preguntas sobre un problema causado por tu codigo" .. en esos casos ".....
